# Arithmetic progression $\dfrac{S_n}{a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $S_m > 0$ but $S_{m+1} < 0$ then what's the maximum of $\dfrac{S_n}{a_n}$ $n<m$ (where $a_n$ is the nth element and ${S_n}$ is the sum of an arithmetic progression).

Yes I know the formula for $S_n = 0.5\cdot n \cdot(a_1+a_n)$ and also that $a_n=(a_1+(n-1)\cdot d)$ and also it follows rather easily that $a_1 > 0$ and $d < 0$ and even that $-0.5\cdot m \cdot d > a_1 > -0.5 \cdot (m-1) \cdot d$ but when I go into finishing the problem it devolves into a gigantic mess. Is there a simpler way I am missing?

Comment: what's m over there?

Comment: Positive number, parameter, given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you start out adding positive numbers that get smaller and smaller (since $d < 0$) until at some point they become negative. You keep adding the negative numbers (which are getting larger and larger in absolute value, i.e. more and more negative) to the sum, until at some point (at $m+1$) the *sum* becomes negative.

The sum keeps increasing while you are adding *positive* numbers to it, but once the numbers turn negative, it starts decreasing (but it's still $> 0$ for a while, until we get to $S_{m+1}$). The maximum value of the ratio will be obtained when $S_k$ is as large as possible and $a_k$ is as small as possible but still positive, whereas the *next* $a$ is negative, i.e. $a_{k+1}< 0$. Can you express $k$ in terms of $m$?

Note: Doing an example with e.g. $a_1 = 3$ and various values of $d$, e.g. $-1.1, -1, -2$ will help I think.